# Partial orders that can be realized by prime ideals of commutative rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, order-theory

Is there a general criterion for which partial orders can be realized by the prime ideals of commutative rings (like we have for topological spaces - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_space)?

And in general, what constraints on the partial order are created by additional classical properties of rings - such as being a UFD, principal domain, etc...?

**Examples for some obvious constraints -**

1. Fields always have just one prime ideal - 0.
2. Local rings have just one maximal ideal.
3. Noetherian rings have only a finite number of minimal primes, and no infinitely ascending **or descending** sequence of prime ideals.
4. Every ring has a minimal prime and a maximal prime.

Comment: It looks like you posted the same question twice in the span of 10 minutes. Please edit the first question instead. Thanks

Comment: Oops, my app said it failed to upload. I deleted the other copy.

Comment: You can really say something a lot stronger than $4$. Every prime ideal contains a minimal prime ideal, and is contained in a maximal prime ideal. Then the poset has a unique greatest element iff the ring is local. Domains would have unique minimal elements, but then so would any ring with a unique minimal prime ideal.

Comment: It's an interesting question but is probably too ambitious. If there were a method of building a ring with a particular poset of prime ideals, then we would be on better ground.

Comment: I thought so originally, but the existence of clear criteria for topological spaces kind of raises my hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered by Eric Wofsey here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229611/partial-orders-realized-by-prime-ideals-on-commutative-rings.

Apparently there is such a criterion. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestley_space.